# Jungle Temple percentage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wonder if anyone knows the approximate chance of a jungle temple being generated in a regular-sized jungle biome. Is there a better chance in a giant jungle biome? Are the chances the same across different platforms (PC PS3 Mobile)?

Comment: Sounds like someone is going to have to rummage through the source code for answers.

Comment: Not a direct solution but I'd like to point out that Jungle Temples only spawn in Jungle and Jungle M biomes, and not in Jungle Edge or Jungle Edge M biomes. So when searching for a jungle temple it is best to avoid the edges of the jungle, head to the centre and burn the trees down to help clear the area and make any temples easier to spot.

Comment: @Pharap yes! Burn it down, with Lemons! your saying what we're all thinking

Comment: @Memor-X Personally I think combustible lemons would have been much more useful than the 32 new splashes they're adding in 1.8. Cave Johnson, we're done here! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbzGLdiICk4

Comment: I would say that there's a higher chance in a larger biome, simply due to the way probability works.

Answer (score 1):

Biome mechanics are not exactly simple.

For best results try a biome mapping utility like [Amidst](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262200-v3-6-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder).

The "odds", however, are not stacked in favor of structures being generated. They are meant to add flavor, not to be common.

Edit: to address your platform-dependent question - the many minecraft platform variants are likely using the biome mechanics identically to their version for java. I would suggest you operate under that assumption until it's proven wrong. Also - you will need seeds.